# Error during Installing Rails in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, installation

First I installed rvm for multi-user using script

```
 \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

and I added users to rvm group.

and rvm seems worked fine. so I installed ruby 1.9.3 and set 1.9.3 as default

and now I tried to install rails with command

```
 gem install rails
```

It seems worked fine, but when fetching json-1.7.6.gem and an error occurs.

```
 ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby extconf.rb
 creating Makefile

 make
 sh: make: Permission denied


 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/json-1.7.6 for inspection.
 Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

So I thought it would be related with permission, so I tried

```
 sudo gem install rails
```

but then this error occurs.

```
 sudo: gem: command not found
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sudo as follows..

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Updated Answer:

our `$PATH` variable needs to include the exact path to your Ruby's bin directory. Adding a directory to the `PATH` does not include it's subfolders. Try adding the bin directory via:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/adam/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin
```

or if you installed the gem using sudo:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin
```

You might want to add this to your `.bashrc` file, so that you don't have to set this manually every time your open up a new bash.

Comment: Thank you! now I can call sudo gem!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rvmsudo` to run sudo commands.  But you should really be using `Gemfiles` to install gems using `Bundler`.